# Node js for loop unable to access variable it print undefiend

Tags: node.js

I am using Node js and use sendmail function

i declare variable **htmlVal** i try to access outside but it print undefiend only

```
function myFunction(){
    var htmlVal;
    Report.find({}, function (err, reports) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the users.");
        for(let reportData of reports){
            User.find({name:reportData.name}, function (err, users) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the users.");
                for (let item of users) {
                    htmlVal = `<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#000000;">
<tr width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<th style="text-align:center; border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;border-right:1px solid #000">Name</th>
</tr>
<tr width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<td style="text-align:center;padding:10px;border:1px solid #000">`+item.name+`</td>
</tr>
</table>`;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(htmlVal);

    const sendmail = require('sendmail')({
        silent:true, 
    })
    sendmail({
        from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Attendance of the Day',
        html: htmlVal
    }, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack);
        console.dir(reply);
    })

}
```

I am using this htmlVal for send email but it send empty only

because i am unable to access **htmlVal** outside

how to access it outside

Comment: The most simple way is to move usage of `htmlVal` under its assignment, right after `for` loop

Comment: If you're using backtick for strings (``) then you shouldn't do string concat: \`+item.name+\` should simply be ${item.name}

Comment: @justin.m.chase it's working backtick myproblem is i am unable to access htmlVal outside

Comment: @iofjuupasli if i use inside multiple mail will go i want to send only one mail

Comment: I know it works but it comlpetely defeats the whole purpose of the backtick, which was added so you don't have to do string concatentation like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
let htmlVal;
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        Report.find({}, function (err, reports) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the users.");

            async.eachSeries(reports, function (value, key, callbackFE) {
                User.find({name:value.name}, function (err, users) {
                    if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the users.");
                    for (let item of users) {
                        htmlVal = `<html></html`;
                    }
                    callbackFE();
                });
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) console.error(err.message);
                callback(null, htmlVal);
            });
        });
    }], function(err, htmlVal) {
    console.log(htmlVal);

    const sendmail = require('sendmail')({
        silent:true, 
    })
    sendmail({
        from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Attendance of the Day',
        html: htmlVal
    }, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack);
        console.dir(reply);
    });
});
```

Comment: callbackFE not a function

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you're encountering is that `Report.find` is an async function, as well as `User.find`, but you're sending your email synchronously.

Or in other words you're sending the email before the report is rendered.

In this case, since you have a second async query and loop inside of `Report.find` you're probably going to want to use the [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) library and then compose your async methods together.

Read about the [`eachSeries`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) function and then render your html inside of the `Reports.find` callback instead of immediately after calling `Report.find`.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are using the variable htmlVar even before a value is getting assigned to it.

sendmail function will get called before the value is assigned to htmlVar because Report.find is a asynchronous function. Either you need to move the sendmail function call inside the callback function or use async/await.

Comment: how to use call back function